# How to Fetch nth value from local storage using JavaScript value

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a JavaScript object/local storage variable

`localStorage.xyz`

When I'm hitting this in console I'm getting the result below.

Example

`{"abc@gmail.com":"342xyza"}`

How can I only fetch the 2nd value `342xyza`?

Comment: Will this result every have any more keys? And will the key always be `abc@gmail.com`? Please provide more information.

Comment: It seems its not second value your are referring. "342xyza" its a value of first key or first element of object, Can you paste how you are storing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse` to create an object out of your localStorage string.(Assuming that it is stored as a JSON like in the example). Once you have the object, you can access the value in the object by using it's key

Sample:

```
var obj;
try {
   obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.xyz);
}catch(e){
   // Handle JSON parse exception
}

// If you know the key beforehand:
console.log(obj['abc@gmail.com'])

// If you don't know the key
console.log(Object.values(obj)[0])
```

Comment: I dont know the key. is there any way to convert the above code in single JS varibale instead of custom code u mentioned

Comment: @jerodev :- no this result will have only 1 key and 1st key is always email id(abc@gmail.com).

Comment: @taylor :- Yes bascially its a first key. Actually this value im getting from the backend so not sure about how backend team is storing this.